# Polkadot wallet signature verification

Tags: polkadot, signatures

I am looking for a way to validate a signature from any Polkadot wallet in `Node.js`. Preferably it would be some lightweight library which supports this since `@polkadot-util/crypto` is a bit too heavy based on my requirements.

Are there any alternative libraries or some other methods that I can use to validate polkadot wallet signatures for a given message using Typescript or Javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Well, you could extract that part from polkadot-util/crypto actually.

Comment: True, I already looked into that, however the implementation seemed quite convoluted and containing multiple dependencies.